# SQL Query -- IF X is shared between two strings in a primary composite key?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, unique, composite-primary-key

Not sure how to explain this, as I have only basic SQL knowledge. I need help with some logic to signal a user when a unique string is referenced more than once in a composite primary key.

A table I use contains a composite primary key which ties a unique "ItemCode" to a repeating  "WarehouseCode". The "QuantityOnHand" column lists how much we have of an item in each warehouse:

```
     _____PK_______
    |              |
ItemCode  |  WarehouseCode  |  QuantityOnHand
---------------------------------------------
   001             A                 100
   001             B                 500
   002             A                 600
   003             B                 250
```

etc.

How do I "signal" (create a boolean value?) when ItemCode 001 is in two separate warehouses?

The end result is a crystal report which somehow alerts the user when an item's total quantity is split between two warehouses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilise GROUP BY and HAVING. For example this query will return a list of ItemCodes and a count of how many warehouses they are in where that count is greater than 1.

```
SELECT ItemCode, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY ItemCode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In crystal you would probably want to create a group on ItemCode and then you can evaluate: `DistinctCount({table.WarehouseCode})` but I would suggest you use SQL `group by ItemCode having count(distinct WarehouseCode) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to do in Crystal than in pure SQL

Using a Crystal function:

```
If {table.ItemCode} = Previous({table.ItemCode})
    Then //we have a duplicate ItemCode, do something to flag it
```

The above assumes that the details have these values and that they were not grouped.  Although, even if they were grouped something like this should do it

```
If {table.ItemCode} = Previous({table.ItemCode})
    and {table.WarehouseCode} <> Previous({table.WarehouseCode})
    Then //we have a duplicate ItemCode
```